# Probabilistic SVM for regression

Tags: python, classification, svm

So I've currently implemented code for binary output for the probabilistic SVM, this is based on Platt's implementation. My question is now, is there something similiar I can do (still probabilistic) when it comes to multi-classification as well as regression and is there some theory that can support me in what I do ?

Comment: This question appears to be more about theory than programming, you might have better luck on the [data science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange site

Comment: [`sklearn.svm`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#multi-class-classification) supports multi-class classification.

Comment: ye, I've actually made the implementation based on that package @pault, but I would like to know in what way its probabilistic and the theory behind it

Comment: @KonradS that question is off topic for this site. The docs I linked have references you can read.

Comment: Im thankful for the links, I'm just unsure of how it takes probabilities into account, it looks to me that it's only a "regular" svm ?